# C++ : User defined class with a member field as an address

Tags: c++, eclipse

If I have a user defined class say

```
 class Student {
  public:
      string name;
      int *grade;
      Student (string a, int b);
}; //Student header
```

and I create an instance of it (after defining the constructor of course) by writing Student t("sam",96);
where 96 is being assigned to the grade member field, how do I access the grade at a later date? t.grade will only give me the address and t->grade will not compile.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Think about this: your member is a pointer. What would it point to?

Comment: It is supposed to point to an integer,  but t.grade will not return the integer. Does *(t.grade) work?

Comment: You're worrying about syntax but you should pay attention to semantics: the thing the pointer points to has to be alive whenever you access it via the pointer.

Comment: Why don't you declare a simple `int` member? I don't understand why you would want a pointer there at all.

Comment: It was an example from class, we are learning about pointers and the like, but when I copied the professors code from her slides it did not work.

Comment: @cryoban Well, how is `grade` initialized in the constructor definition?

Comment: Our professor did not create a constructor for us, but I created one where grade was initialized like this int *grade = new int; so it will hold an address of an integer on the heap

Comment: `int *grade = new int;` will create a local variable in your construcot, which shadows the member variable. You'll need to write `grade = new int;` inside your constructors body. To dereference the pointer outside just write `*(t.grade)`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int x = *(t.grade);
```

Comment: To help readers understand your solution, consider including a short description of your code and how it solves the posted question

Answer (score -1):

Since you have not method defined which explains why you would use a pointer for grade it is probably not intended.

So a solution would be:

```
class Student {
public:
   string name;
   int grade;
   Student (string a, int b){
       name = a;
       grade = b;
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

t is not a pointer, therefore it can't be used as an l-value for the member of pointer operator(->). I suggest this type of instantiation:

Student* t = new Student("Sam",96);
                                                                                                                t->(any public member of class Student);

If you just made the simple type int not a pointer, then you would be able to access the value from t like t->grade. Look into smart pointers, and good luck.